# Encrypt query string embeded in a template field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, encryption, query-string

I try to Encrypt my query string through the following class :

[Encrypt Query String .](http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx)

The problem is:

My link is in a `gridview` , I don't know how to use the encryption method through the eval expression in a correct way .

This what i have tried :

**My .aspx** :

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <a id="btnShowPopup6" runat="server" class="thickbox" href='<%#"PageDetail.aspx?QueryStringModule.Encrypt(code="+Eval("t_code")+"&serial="+Eval("t_Serial")+"&year="+Eval("t_Year")+"&AR=1"+"&TBiframe=true&height=600&width=950)"%>'>
  <asp:Image ID="Image43" runat="server" ToolTip="confirm" ImageUrl="Images/ok-blue.png"
   Width="20" Height="20" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you show what HTML gets generated for the href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your href= to the following and it should work.

```
<%#"PageDetail.aspx" + QueryStringModule.Encrypt("code="+Eval("t_code")+"&serial="+Eval("t_Serial")+"&year="+Eval("t_Year")+"&AR=1"+"&TBiframe=true&height=600&width=950")%>
```

By the way do not re-use your encryption key for anything other than this query string module.  Unfortunately what the httpmodule does is creates a *"cryptographic oracle"* whereby you can supply any plaintext and it will return to you a valid cipher text encrypted with your key.  So for example if you go to pagedetail.aspx?myname=moe it will encrypt myname=moe for me and give me a value that's been encrypted with your key.  If you use this value in other parts of your code for some type of verification or information hiding I can generate the encrypted strings at will.

Answer (score 1):

create a code behind method and pass your data you want to encrypt..
which returns a link

call the method in your ItemTemplate

the method may be like this...

```
protected string getCode(string t_code, string t_Serial, string t_Year)
    {
        return "<a href=PageDetail.aspx?" + QueryStringModule.Encrypt("code=" + t_code + "&serial=" + t_Serial + "&year=" + t_Year + "&AR=1" + "&TBiframe=true&height=600&width=950") + ">code</a>";
    }
```

now use it like below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YOUR LINK NAME">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <%# getCode(Eval("t_code").ToString(), Eval("t_Serial").ToString(), Eval("t_Year").ToString()) %>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```